# ios - how to store mail contacts in an array

Tags: ios, email, save, contacts

in  my ios app when the user clicks a button it opens email part by which the user can send a common mail to all.

Now my question is whenever the user types an email address in the `to:` column i want the addresses to be stored automatically to an Array, so that the next time when the user clicks the `to` column i will be listing out the emails he have used so far.

I want to store the text typed there to an array.

how to do this, please help me friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the emails in NSMutableArray and save it in NSUserDefaults for future, each time user enter email you have to create new temp NSMutableArray which init with NSUserDefaults's array then append last entry to it after that and save it again in NSUserDefault by replacing last value.

Comment: can you please say how to do it, with sample code. When the user types how to store them into NSUserDefaults......pls

Comment: `NSMutableArray *UD = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"results"]];

 NSArray *R = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[name text]],
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",(scor*100/maxs)],
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[UserData use] Topic]],
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[UserData use] Grade]],
      [NSString stringWithString:@"39"],nil];
 
 [UD addObject:R];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UD forKey:@"results"];`

Comment: you can customize NSArray *R as per your need you also can chose your datatype like NSString instead of NSArray for *R , because i think your requirement is only for an email address that is a NSString type